c# - Serilog.Sinks.Prometheus not working
I have a project that need use Serilog.Sinks.Prometheus as logging, but when i try some solution i found, but still not working.
This is my appsettings.json
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Prometheus", "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Prometheus",
      "Args": {
        "counterNameTemplate": "Serilog",
        "counterDescription": "Serilog-counter"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Console"
    },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "Logs/File-API-.log",
        "rollingInterval": "Day"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ],
  "Properties": {
    "ApplicationName": "Name"
  }
},

here is my service builder
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) => configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

This log that be created on log file :

This the result if i try to search by keyword that exists on file, but not found, but can found serilog counter / description that i set in appsettings.json

Am I missing something ?
I would be glad for any help.
